# Fancy Title/Headline with Horizontal Rule and Multiple Text Elements in ConTeXt

Tags: titles, context, headline, modules

I want to create a title like the following:

```
_________________________________________________________________________________
|                             |                                    | Sufix      |
| Prefix unwrapped (CAPS)     | Unwrapped title (Small Caps)       | wraped     |
|                             |                                    | as needed  |
=================================================================================
        Ba ba                                  Ba ba
•     Sub text 1     •   Sub text 2   •      Sub text 3       •    Sub text 4   •
          Ba                                Black Sheep
```

It needs to be:

- stretched full with of the page
- underlined with colour (=)
- there are no bothers on top, left, right or middle (|, _)
- Subtext which is separated by a separator character (•) which is centre or top-aligned and adjusted for optimal fit.

So far what I have done is (1st part of the title/header):

```
\define[3]\TITLE{\midaligned{\framed[frame=off,align=middle,bottomframe=on,framecolor=blue]
                                {\inframed[frame=off]{{\tfa\WORD#1}: {\tfb\sc#2}}\inframed[frame=off]{{\tfa, #3}}}}}
```

But this does not produce the desired results.

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you please add a complete minimal working example? In particular, do you plan to use this as a standalone macro or as part of Context's heading mechanism (chapter, section, etc)?

Comment: This is for one-off use as a title for CV.

Comment: Have you considered using tables?

Comment: I am pretty new to ConTeXt. I started using it only today. I am not fully aware of all the options. No, I have not tried tables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand the specs, so let me try to answer this iteratively.

- I am assuming that the width of `Prefix + Title < \textwdith`. If not, then one of these two must also wrap.
- It is not clear how `Prefix` and `Title` should be aligned vertically. I chose middle aligned (which is called `lohi` in ConTeXt)

Conceptually, the simplest method is to use TABLEs. So, the basic macro is:

```
\define[3]\TITLE
  {\startTABLE[setups=table:title]
      \NC #1 \NC #2 \NC #3 \NC \NR
    \stopTABLE}
```

Now, all we need to do is define the setups `table:title` to get the right formatting, which can be done as follows:

```
\startsetups table:title
  \setupTABLE[each][each][frame=off,bottomframe=on,rulethickness=2bp]
  \setupTABLE[column][1][style=WORD, align=lohi]
  \setupTABLE[column][2][style=\sc,  align=lohi]
  \setupTABLE[column][3][align={hyphenated,tolerant}]
\stopsetups
```

That's it!

Here is the complete code with the output:

```
\startsetups table:title
  \setupTABLE[each][each][frame=off,bottomframe=on,rulethickness=2bp]
  \setupTABLE[column][1][style=WORD, align=lohi]
  \setupTABLE[column][2][style=\sc,  align=lohi]
  \setupTABLE[column][3][align={hyphenated,tolerant}]
\stopsetups

\define[3]\TITLE
  {\startTABLE[setups=table:title]
      \NC #1 \NC #2 \NC #3 \NC \NR
    \stopTABLE}

\showframe % To visualize the page frame
\starttext

\TITLE{prefix}{Unwrapped title}{\dorecurse{5}{A very long text\space}}

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

The top and side frames are due to `\showframe` just to show that the table is extended to the edge of the page boundary.

Comment: There are two options to get smallcaps: `style=\sc` or `style=smallcaps`.  The first internally does `\setfontfeature{smallcaps}` whereas the second does `\doaddfeature{f:smallcaps}`.  No idea what is the difference (if any).

Comment: In my experience, `style=\sc` works with some fonts while `style=smallcaps` does not **and vice-versa**. With LM, `style=smallcaps` does not give the small caps effect.